# Dygraphs : I don't want points, even when the series is highlighted

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Is it possible to only plot lines in dygraph, even when the series is highlighted?

`drawPoints : false` works well, but not in `highlightSeriesOpts`. and it seems like the minimum value acceptable for `highlightCircleSize` is 1.
I am plotting multiple series on the same dygraph and when I mouse over, I only want a line highlighted, I don't want a point per series cluttering the graph.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the minimum value acceptable for highlightCircleSize is 1?" A value of zero works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/8989/

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response ! I guess I had put highlightCircleSize inside highlightSeriesOpts and it wasn't working ....